# Error insert data into table

Tags: php

I have follow an instruction on how to create a shopping cart, I want to make a modification so the shopping cart system can be use as a restaurant system for staff to record customer order, so the system do not need to record the customer details. I have error when i try to insert all the chosen data into table and it's echo **sucess**, but no data inserted into database. the error happens in cart.php.

Here is the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\emakengku\cart.phpon line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: quantity inC:\xampp\htdocs\emakengku\cart.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\emakengku\cart.phpon line 9

Here is the code:

index2.php

```
<?
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("connection.php");
if(isset($_GET['page'])){

    $pages=array("products", "cart");
    if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {

        $_page=$_GET['page'];

    }else{

        $_page="products";

    }

}else{

$_page="products";

}
?>



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<body>
</body>
</html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="main">
<?php require($_page.".php");     ?>

</div>

<div id="sidebar">
<h1>Cart</h1>

<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN (";

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
$sql.=$id.",";
}
$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

?>
<p><?php echo $row['name'] ?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?></p>
<?php }

?>

<hr />
<a href="index2.php?page=cart">Go to Cart</a>


<?php





}else{

echo "<p>Your Cart is empty</p>";

}
?>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Products.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){

        $id=intval($_GET['id']);

        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){

            $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;

        }else{

            $sql_s="SELECT * FROM products
                WHERE id_product={$id}";
            $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
            if(mysql_num_rows($query_s)!=0){
                $row_s=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);



                    $_SESSION['cart'][$row_s['id_product']]=array(
                            "quantity" => 1,
                            "price" => $row_s['price']

                            );


                }else{

                    $message="This product id it's invalid!";


        }
        }
        }




?>


<h1>Product List</h1>
<?php 

    if(isset($message)){
    echo "<h2>$message</h2>";
    }
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC";

$query=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
    <td>RM <?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
    <td><a href="index2.php?page=products&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>">Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

</table>
```

cart.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])) {

    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $quantity=$_POST["quantity"];
    $price=$_POST["price"];
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO order (name, quantity, price)  
values('$name', '$quantity', '$price')"; 
mysql_query($sql_insert);  

echo "sucess!";

}

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 
 foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val) {
    if($val==0) {
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
    }else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;
    


    }
    }
 

 }

?>



<a href="index2.php?page=products">Go back to product page</a>
<h1>View Cart</h1>

<form method="post" action"index2.php?page=cart">

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Item Price</th>



</tr>
<?php

    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN (";

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
$sql.=$id.",";
}
$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$totalprice=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']*$row['price'];
    $totalprice+=$subtotal;

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?>"</td>
<td>RM <?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
<td>RM <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']*$row['price'] ?></td>



</tr>



<?php 
}

?>
<tr>
<td>Total Price: <?php echo $totalprice  ?></td>


</tr>

</table>
<button type="submit" name="submit"> Update Cart</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit2"> Update Cart</button>


</form>
<br />
<p> To remove an item,set the quantity to 0</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

Your form is broken, you're missing the name, quantity etc inputs you later try to use in the script (`$_POST['name']` etc) - in file cart.php.

It's hard to find it, because the code is huge mess, but I didn't manage to find any inputs with those names.

Also, besides the obvious flaws like using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, you really should not mix logic and view this way. Doing database query in the middle of rendering a form is NOT GOOD.

If you used some MVC framework, it'd be much cleaner.

Comment: the instruction i followed just finish until the update cart, but it didnt teach how to submit the confirmed data,so i try by myself to create it.im still learning and this is my first time creating a shopping cart.sorry

Comment: You should probably look for some quality tutorial instead of the junk you've followed thus far. What you have is very bad quality code, and using outdated functions.